# How to add the value in shared_preferences to the token when flutter uses the dio request

Tags: flutter

To use dio to request the network, I need to add a token to the headers. My token is stored in shared_preferences. I get the value of the token in sp when I use the request, but flutter is stored asynchronously, so maybe at the time of the request.

How to get the value in sp?

```
HttpHelper() {
//This is the value read from shared_preferences
String token = SPUtils.getInstance().getString(TMCommonConstant.AUTH_TOKEN);
_options = Options(
    connectTimeout: 50000,
    receiveTimeout: 3000,
    headers: {"auth-token": token});//use here 
_dio = new Dio(_options);
}
```

When I use it, I call this constructor. Here I get the value back to a null value.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make the function `async`, so it will be like this

```
HttpHelper() async{
//This is the value read from shared_preferences
String token = await SPUtils.getInstance().getString(TMCommonConstant.AUTH_TOKEN);
_options = Options(
    connectTimeout: 50000,
    receiveTimeout: 3000,
    headers: {"auth-token": token});//use here 
_dio = new Dio(_options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have the idea. The Future function can still perform async in its then so that I solved the problem.